# android kotlin view bind IllegalStateException must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an Android app that is released on the Play Store.

When I check the crash reports, I saw something weird.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_item.*

class ItemFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        presenter.getItem(args.item)
    }

    override fun onItemLoaded(item: Item) {
        tvDesc.text = item.desc // in here: Exception occurrs
    }
}
```

And below is my presenter class:

```
class ItemPresenter(
        private val view: ItemContract.View,
        private val itemsRepository: ItemsRepository,
        private val ioScheduler: Scheduler = Schedulers.io(),
        private val uiScheduler: Scheduler = AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(),
        private val disposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
) : ItemContract.Presenter {

    override fun getItem(name: String) {
        disposable.add(
            itemsRepository.getItem(name)
                .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
                .observeOn(uiScheduler)
                .subscribe {
                    view.onItemLoaded(it)
                }
        )
    }

}
```

When I run on my phone, it works fine.
But according to the crash reports, a few devices show the IllegalStateExceptions.

Why?

Should I use old-style binding? like "findViewById"

Answer (score 0):

My theory:

Your presenter is called during your Fragment's `onViewCreated`. But the process to get the item is asynchronous, so while that is happening, the fragment can be quickly detached/stopped/paused/etc. and therefore be in an illegal state to receive updates. It's hard to tell without more context, access to the project, and thorough debugging, but it's a common problem to call back onto a Fragment whose state is invalid.

There are various ways to mitigate, control, and avoid these issues. Among them, is simply using [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) or even making your presenter Lifecycle Aware, and not calling `view.onItemLoaded(it)` if the fragment lifecycle is "at least" started.

I don't know if your presenter has an onStop/Destroy/etc. that stops/disposes the subscription in your composite disposables pool, but if the fragment is not ready to receive the response it requested, then the fragment should let the presenter know that it's no longer ready to receive that and that is should be discarded/stopped/etc. If you use Lifecycle/Livedata, this is handled by you, provided you wire the things required for it to work.

I suggest looking at the various [Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack) components offered by Google.